# Javascript hide certain table rows when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html-table, hide, rows, show

I want to hide certain rows in my table when I click a button as well as retain certain rows. For example, I clicked "Show Fire-based champs" button. It will only show champs that have the Fire attribute and will hide the rest (from the same table). I clicked another button called "Show Water-based champs" that will only show champs that have the Water attribute and will hide the rest etc. and will be the same for other buttons. Anyone can make a code for it? I'm not experienced in JS.

Here is how the main table looks like (just a sample, there are a lot more table rows).

```
<table border="1" width="800">
<thead><tr>
    <th>Hero</th>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Offensive Skill</th>
    <th>Passive Skill</th>
    <th>Ultimate</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td><a class="holy">Arcana</a></td>
    <td>the Arcane Manipulator</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Arcane Destroyer</td></tr>

    <tr><td><a class="fire">Azakiel</a></td>
    <td>the Blood Mage</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Elf Blood</td>
    <td>Call of the Phoenix</td></tr>

    <tr><td><a class="wind">Bahamut</a></td>
    <td>the King of the Skies</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Mega Flare</td></tr>

    <tr><td><a class="dark">Carinblack</a></td>
    <td>the Dark Assailant</td>
    <td>Sword Bash</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Blade of the Dark</td></tr>

    <tr><td><a class="earth">Dran</a></td>
    <td>the Steel Beast</td>
    <td>Rushing Tackle</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Rolling Thunder</td></tr>

    <tr><td><a class="water">Fenrir</a></td>
    <td>the Water Emperor</td>
    <td>Water Barrage</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Waterfall</td></tr>

    <tr><td><a class="thunder">Larza</a></td>
    <td>the Lightning Heroine</td>
    <td>Staff of Lightning</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Storm Surge</td></tr>

    <tr><td><a class="thunder">Razor</a></td>
    <td>the Thunder Emperor</td>
    <td>Thunder Strike</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Thunderstorm</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide)

For example, when "Show fire-based champs" is clicked, do:

```
$('tbody tr').hide() //Hide all rows
$('tbody tr:has(a.fire)').show() //Show all fire rows
```

[Here is a jsfiddle that has all the code in it](http://jsfiddle.net/MChfU/)

HTML code:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0b1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function show(champ){
  $('tbody tr').hide()   
  $('tbody tr:has(a.'+champ+')').show()
 }


</script>


</head>
<body>
  <table border="1" width="800">
<thead><tr>
    <th>Hero</th>
    <th>Class</th>
    <th>Offensive Skill</th>
    <th>Passive Skill</th>
    <th>Ultimate</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td><a class="holy">Arcana</a></td>
    <td>the Arcane Manipulator</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Arcane Destroyer</td></tr>

    <tr><td><a class="fire">Azakiel</a></td>
    <td>the Blood Mage</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Elf Blood</td>
    <td>Call of the Phoenix</td></tr>

    <tr><td><a class="wind">Bahamut</a></td>
    <td>the King of the Skies</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Mega Flare</td></tr>

    <tr><td><a class="dark">Carinblack</a></td>
    <td>the Dark Assailant</td>
    <td>Sword Bash</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Blade of the Dark</td></tr>

    <tr><td><a class="earth">Dran</a></td>
    <td>the Steel Beast</td>
    <td>Rushing Tackle</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Rolling Thunder</td></tr>

    <tr><td><a class="water">Fenrir</a></td>
    <td>the Water Emperor</td>
    <td>Water Barrage</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Waterfall</td></tr>

    <tr><td><a class="thunder">Larza</a></td>
    <td>the Lightning Heroine</td>
    <td>Staff of Lightning</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Storm Surge</td></tr>

    <tr><td><a class="thunder">Razor</a></td>
    <td>the Thunder Emperor</td>
    <td>Thunder Strike</td>
    <td> - </td>
    <td>Thunderstorm</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="show(&quot;fire&quot;)">Show fire</button>
<button onclick="show(&quot;water&quot;)">Show water</button>
<button onclick="show(&quot;thunder&quot;)">Show thunder</button>
<button onclick="show(&quot;dark&quot;)">Show dark</button>
<button onclick="show(&quot;earth&quot;)">Show earth</button>
<button onclick="show(&quot;holy&quot;)">Show holy</button>
<button onclick="show(&quot;wind&quot;)">Show wind</button>
<button onclick="$('tbody tr').show()  ">Show all</button>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Do I need to replicate the same script? eg.
`code`fasfasfs

    <script type="text/javascript">

 function show(water){
  $('tbody tr').hide()   
  $('tbody tr:has(a.'+water+')').show()
 }


</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 function show(fire){
  $('tbody tr').hide()   
  $('tbody tr:has(a.'+fire+')').show()
 }


</script>

`code`

Comment: @Ralphx3589: nah, the function calls in the button take care of this.

Comment: So do I just copy the HTML code as is? No more editing?

EDIT: oh thanks! It works as I intended it to be! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Ralphx3589: yep. If it worked, hit the green checkmark next to my answer to "accept" it :)

Comment: Wait, it works on the fiddle thing but when I placed it on the notepad, the buttons doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ralphx3589: oops, I forgot to add jquery. I'm using jQuery 2, but you can replace that with your desired version. Try now :)